# How can I add a related record from its parents partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, record, nested-attributes

I have a table of reviews and comments, where a review can have many comments.

How can I have the add new comment form held inside the review partial?

What I have at the moment gives a "undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class" error.

**_review.html.erb**

```
<div class="review">    
  <div class="review_content">
    <h2 class="review_partial_title"><%= review.title %></h2>        
    <p class="review_body"><%= review.body %></p>       
  </div>

  <div class="clearall"></div>

  <div class="comments_container">
    <%= render :partial => 'comments/comment', :collection => review.comments %>
  </div>

  <div class="add_comment_container">
    <%= form_for [@review, @comment] do |f| %>    
      <p>body: <br>
      <%= f.text_field :body %></p>

      <%= submit_tag %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="clearall"></div>
</div>
```

**review.rb**

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
end
```

**routes**

```
resources :reviews do
  resources :comments
end
```

Thanks for any help its much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
<%= form_for [@review, @comment] do |f| %>
```

To this:

```
<%= form_for [review, review.comments.build] do |f| %>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it pretty much works only I get a Cannot redirect to nil! error. I've added the controller to my question, any idea what could solve this?

Comment: Sorry, just realised it was a problem with the comments controller not the reviews, your answer works great thanks very much!